# jQuery caching problems on local test server

Tags: jquery, caching

I am making a website on a test server I have running, so I can easily go to 127.0.0.1 and it will show me the results.

I have been having an issue that only seems to effect Jquery loading, I use the following suggested method of requesting Jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I don't know how exactly to diagnose what's going on, but it seems like jQuery is getting cached to 127.0.0.1 and not loading, which is only a guess. The code on the page that depends on jQuery will error and bootstrap will give the error that jQuery is required, but if I load a different site (not a local site, something on the internet) that includes jQuery it seems to temporary fix the problem until I refresh the test site twice.

When I try to load the direct link to the jQuery file on the jQuery website when the issue is happening, I get an 'Unable to connect' error, the Firefox network tab shows a GET request to the jQuery.com URL and the response tab shows nothing at all.

This seems like it wouldn't happen to an outside visitor if I were to open port 80 and load the site with a different IP address, but I still can't figure out why this caching issue keeps happening given the fact that the jQuery file is being requested from the jQuery servers themselves. It's affected both apache2 and nginx with default settings, no special caching or anything like that.

I have noscript installed but I can't see any settings that would seem to cause this at first glance, 127.0.0.1 and code.jquery.com are both whitelisted, ABE is disabled, and is otherwise running in the 'default' mode (forbid scripts globally is obviously NOT enabled).

Comment: what makes you think that if its cached it won't load?

Comment: you can always try google cdn as well

Comment: @MehulMohan Because once I have been using the test site, it stops the jQuery file from loading (even from direct requests in the URL bar, it just doesn't return any data)

Then, if I force reloading the file without the cache (ctrl+F5) it loads the remote file like normal

Comment: Are all your other script tags following the jQuery load? If not, caching/network speed could cause weird load patterns which only sometimes allow the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try CTRL + SHIFT + J in firefox. you can filter on [ABE] to doublecheck if noscript's ABE really isn't getting in your way.
Once you have the appropriate error message you can see what rule got in your way and build on allowing it.
Noscript blocks any site from accessing local resources by default, see system rule.